# Object as Double

Tags: java

I have a `Map<Object,Object>` which contains String as a key and Double as value.
To extract the double value ,I would do a `((Number)en.getValue()).doubleValue()` .
However,for obvious reasons I want to do defensive programming to check if the value is really a Double.
How would I achieve it?

The instanceOf is not the solution  - as it does not seem to recognize the inherent double in this case.

Comment: Just use Map<String, Double>

Comment: That is not an option as it is passed in

Comment: "_defensive programming_" and generics using `Object` are not compatible.

Comment: "The instanceOf is not the solution - as it does not seem to recognize the inherent double in this case." Please show a [mcve] showing this. It should work fine.

Comment: As you cast it to number, make the check instanceOf against Number, maybe its not all Doubles in the Map

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
Object o = en.getValue();
if (o instanceof Number) {
  // do something with ((Number)o).doubleValue();
} else {
  // not a double
}
```

This works for:

- map.put("abc",new Double(12));
- map.put("def",15); // boxed to Integer which is a Number
- map.put("ghi",15.0d); // boxed to a Double, also a Number

If you want to ensure that only Double specifically is handled, then do change instanceof check to Double instead of Number.

If you still feel instanceof is not the answer, can you explain why?

Comment: i think he is actually reffering to an object . if so `instanceof` wouldnt be of much help

Comment: how so?  instanceof works on any object and returns true if the subject is and instance of the specified type or a subclass of that type.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can help:

```
Class<? extends Object> className = obj.getClass();

if (className.getName().contains("Number")){
 //check to see if Double  
//add the object to the Map    
}else {
  //convert it to whatever and do error handling 
}
```